# Android - Get Notified when a new access point is added?

Tags: android, wifi, notifications, wifimanager

I was wondering is it possible to get a notification of when a new configured network is added to the WifiManager in Android?

I know you can get the current list of configured networks

[getConfiguredNetworks](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks%28%29)

But is it possible to get notification of when a new one is added?

I dont see anything in the WifiManager that would be helpful.

Has anyone any other ideas? Or insight into how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up a broadcast receiver for [`NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION)? I just looked through some of the [WifiManager source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/WifiService.java) and [Settings.git source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=saveConfiguration) and it seems like that might do the trick. I haven't tried myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of how to use the Notification bar, and play with the notification in:
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/09/learn-by-example-using-notification-bar/

Maybe this can help you.